# How do I get random enemies to appear from list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, pygame

I'm trying to get a random car to appear from a list of cars saved in variables. The issue seems to be it chooses a random car from the list and doesn't change it while the game is being played. I'd like to change the car each time the previous car goes off screen.

Each time the game starts it chooses one car from the random list, but does not change the car each time the game loop runs.

I believe the problem lies in this bit of code

```
randomCars = [car1, car2, car3, car4, car5, car6, car7, car8]
enemy = random.choice(randomCars)
```

I have pasted the full code below:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

#############

#############

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (200, 0, 0)
green = (0, 200, 0)
bright_red = (255, 0, 0)
bright_green = (0, 255, 0)
block_color = (53, 115, 255)

crash_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("crash.mp3")

car_width = 55

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Super Racer')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gameIcon = pygame.image.load('carIcon.png')

backgroundImage = pygame.image.load("background.png")
backgroundImage = pygame.transform.scale(backgroundImage, (800, 600))
gameDisplay.blit(backgroundImage, (0, 0))





pygame.display.set_icon(gameIcon)

pause = False


# crash = True

def score(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
    text = font.render("SCORE: " + str(count), True, red)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0, 0))

def load_image(name_img):
    car = pygame.image.load(name_img)
    car = pygame.transform.scale(car, (60, 100)) # resize graphic
    return car.convert_alpha() # remove whitespace from graphic

carImg = load_image('racecar.png')
enemies_list = ['diablo.png', 'aventador.png', 'nsx.png', 'bike.png', 'Mach6.png', 'speeder.png', 'Stingray.png', 'slr.png' ] # add all other cars
randomCars = [load_image(img) for img in enemies_list]

def things(enemy, thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    gameDisplay.blit(enemy, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def car(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x, y))


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def crash():
    ####################################

    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(crash_sound)
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    ####################################
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("You Crashed", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        button("Play Again", 150, 450, 100, 50, green, bright_green, game_loop)
        button("Quit", 550, 450, 100, 50, red, bright_red, quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x, y, w, h))
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((x + (w / 2)), (y + (h / 2)))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()


def unpause():
    global pause
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    pause = False


def paused():
    ############
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    #############
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        button("Continue", 150, 450, 100, 50, green, bright_green, unpause)
        button("Quit", 550, 450, 100, 50, red, bright_red, quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


def game_intro():
    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Super Racer", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("LEGGO!", 150, 450, 100, 50, green, bright_green, game_loop)
        button("Quit", 550, 450, 100, 50, red, bright_red, quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


def game_loop():
    global pause
    enemy = random.choice(randomCars)
    ############

    pygame.mixer.music.load('bgmusic.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    ############
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    enemy_speed = 4
    thing_width = 55
    thing_height = 95
    enemy = random.choice(randomCars)
    thingCount = 1

    dodged = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    pause = True
                    paused()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change

        gameDisplay.blit(backgroundImage, (0, 0))

        things(enemy, thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, block_color)

        thing_starty += enemy_speed
        car(x, y)
        score(dodged)

        if x > display_width - car_width or x < 0:
            crash()

        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
            dodged += 1
            #enemy_speed += .25
            if dodged % 5 == 0:
                enemy_speed += (dodged * 1)


        if y < thing_starty + thing_height:
            #print('y crossover')

            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx + thing_width:
                #print('x crossover')
                crash()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Off-topic, but you could neaten up the `car1 = ...` section with a simple utility method / list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks, I plan to go in and neaten things up after I get everything working correctly.

Comment: why not just move `enemy = random.choice(randomCars)` at the beginning of the `game_loop` function ? this way `enemy` is declared each time the loop restarts (`enemy` may need to be be a global variable too if called outside)

Comment: I tried that, it made sense to me. It unfortunately doesn't work, i'm not sure why.

Comment: *, or `enemy` coud be passed as another parameter in `things` function

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but the problem remains.

Comment: sorry, i misread your question, you need to call `enemy = random.choice(randomCars)` ALSO when the enemy  goes out of the screen, in `if thing_starty > display_height:`...

Comment: I edited the main code please see above.. Problem remains

Comment: Please don't post so much code here. We just want to see a [short, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows us what you've tried and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, im not sure how to piece out the runnable part. I have only just started.

Comment: It looks like all you have to do is to get a new random car when the current car leaves the screen. In this if clause `if thing_starty > display_height:` add another `enemy = random.choice(randomCars)` line.

Comment: Thanks all the solution from skrx worked!

Comment: Please upvote helpful answers and accept your favorite by clicking on the checkmark to indicate that the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal example. Just use `random.choice` to get a new car out of the list as soon as the current car leaves the screen.

```
import random
import pygame


pygame.init()

CAR_IMG1 = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
CAR_IMG1.fill((10, 150, 200))
CAR_IMG2 = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
CAR_IMG2.fill((210, 150, 0))
CAR_IMG3 = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
CAR_IMG3.fill((10, 250, 0))

CARS = [CAR_IMG1, CAR_IMG2, CAR_IMG3]


def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    car = random.choice(CARS)
    pos_x = random.randrange(screen_rect.width-30)
    pos_y = -50

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

        pos_y += 15
        if pos_y > screen_rect.height:
            car = random.choice(CARS)
            pos_x = random.randrange(screen_rect.width-30)
            pos_y = -50

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        screen.blit(car, (pos_x, pos_y))

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I also recommend to take a look at the [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) class which would be useful to store the position of the car and for the collision detection. I use a rect object (the `screen_rect`) in the example to store the size of the screen. Surfaces have a `.get_rect()` method that returns a rect object.

Answer (score 0):

First initialize your list of enemy car images from which to choose one.

`randomCars = [carImg1, carImg2, carImg3, carImg4]`

Inside the game_loop() function but outside of the main loop set `enemy = random.choice(randomCars)`

Inside the main loop of the game_loop() function check to see if the enemy went off the screen. If so, set the enemy variable to a new random car.

```
if thing_starty > display_height:
    # Reset enemy image
    enemy = random.choice(randomCars)
    # Reset thing co-ordinates
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
```

If the `enemy = random.choice(randomCars)` line of code doesn't work you could also try indexing the `randomCars` list with a random integer.

`randomCarsIndex = random.randint(0, len(randomCars) - 1)
 enemy = randomCars[randomCarsIndex]`

Hope this helps!